# Spline function with unknown knots

Tags: r, splines

Does anybody know whether R has a package/routine for estimating spline function with unknown number of knots?

Comment: and `spline` does not work why?

Comment: please clarify. Are you looking for packages that fit so-called *free-knot spline* models, i.e., regression splines where the number and location of knots must also be determined using the observed data?

Comment: Hi - yes, you are perfectly right - I'm looking for an estimator of splines where the number and location of knots must be estimated and using the observed data (time serie data).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the facilities for fitting smoothing splines in the `gam` package.